# Log4Net DB logging working on Development but not Live server

Tags: .net, log4net

We are using Log4Net logging on one of our service applications to log to both File and DB. On our development server both logging types work without issue. However on our Staging and Live servers the DB logging does not work. File logging works fine however.

I have confirmed that SQL permissions are correct, and the log tables/triggers/constraints are all the same on both systems.

I should mention that we are using config transforms in order to change the DB that will be logged to depending on our environment. I can confirm that the correct DB is being injected into the config however.

I am currently unable to enable log4Net debug logging due to other constraints. Is there anything else is should be checking? Other config? Or will i have to work out a way for us to enable log4Net debuging.

Configuration can be found below (Sql config redacted):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="log4netdb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=[dbname];Initial Catalog=[tableName];
    User Id=[username];Password=[password];" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Log4Net Config:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Scheduler_Log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="log4netdb" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO LOG ([Date],[Application],[UserName],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[class],[method],[line]) VALUES (@log_date, @application, @user, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @class, @method, @line)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@application" />
    <dbType value="string" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <key value="log4japp" />
      <conversionPattern value="%property{log4japp}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@user" />
    <dbType value="string" />
    <size value="100" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <key value="log4net:UserName" />
      <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:UserName}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@class" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%class" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@method" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%method" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@line" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%line" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: A few quick things that come to my mind, 1. is the SQL server accessible from the prod machine? 2. Is dbo the owner of the LOG table? Do you have access to check the event log on the prod box to check for any errors there?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes, and unfortunately none of these provided any more insight.

Comment: Since log4net 1.12, you can reference a connection string by name in the log4net config  - `<connectionStringName value="log4netdb" />`

Comment: If you have not noticed this is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: What I noticed was that in your configuration you have `<connectionString value="log4netdb" />` - that's `connectionString` rather than `connectionStringName`, which would be why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that used a transform to directly replace the connection string in the log4Net config section rather then the connection strings.

```
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
  <connectionString value="Data Source=[server];Initial Catalog=[table];User Id=[user];Password=[password];" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
</appender>
```